# How to bypass FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, filestream, filenotfoundexception

I have an text file which has some settings parameters for my project. My desktop layer reads this file. Therewithal , web layer's project read from from Server's MapPath.

FileStream has no operator to bypass an exception.I have tried to Exists control. But , i just need to bypass FileNotFoundException.

Comment: If you want just to bypass this exception then add try{ //open file }catch(FileNofFoundException){ //do what you want }

Comment: How about surround it with a try-catch and handle the exception?

Comment: "*I have tried to Exists control*"... what have you tried? Exceptions should really be used for handling errors, not controlling program flow - if you expect that the file may not exist, you should check for its existence, or lack of, and handle each case appropriately.

Comment: What do you *mean* by bypassing the exception? You want it to *pretend* it found the file and conjure its contents out of thin air?

Comment: I have tried to catch exception with FileNotFoundException . But , it stiil writes on Output Window during my project is compiling. Such as ,  @PiotrWojsa

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions,

Comment: Actually , i already catched the error. I don't want to see this errors all the time (Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll)on  Visual Studio 2017' output window .

Comment: Then check whether the file exists before trying to access it - if it doesn't exist don't try to read from it, so no exception is thrown

Comment: @Diado - it still could be thrown, no way to make that concurrency-safe. But still the right answer, for total reliability do both.

Comment: @DevIst - not sure what you actually want. Describe the actual flow (expected outcome) better. Seeing an exception in the VS output window is not a problem at all.

Comment: @DevIst report a feature request in visual studio backlog,

Answer (score 2):

Place the code in a `try catch`.

```
try
{
   //read
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
   //do logging for this silent catch
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
if (File.Exists(path)
{
    // read file,
}
```

Another way,

```
if (File.Exists(path)
{
    try
    {
        // read file,
    }
    catch (Some other exception related to file, read access violation, etc.)
    {
        handle exception,
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about checking the file exists or not?
if so, you can prevent throwing FileNotFoundException.
[Can not provide complete solution/feedback as we aren't sure about your actual implementation]

```
If(!File.Exists(<path_to_file>)
     return;
// continue doing the rest only if file exists
```

Hope this helps. let us know if require more clarifications. It Would be nice if you could post your method implementation or at least a pseudo code for us to understand the actual problem you trying to solve.

Cheers,

Comment: This introduces a race condition.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, appreciate if you could elaborate a bit on the race condition concern. thx

Comment: Between the test and the removal the file could be removed and still throw FileNotFound

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, good catch, thanks. But the subject issue doesn't talk about deleting the file. Sounds like he wants read the file if it's exists and no where mentioned about cleaning/deleting the file.
Did I missed anything in the question?

Comment: The question is(was?) to not have the read throw. There is no way to prevent that. 
Any process could delete the file so the method has to be allowed to throw. All you can do is handle it.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand your concern.

Comment: Yes , the question was about read throw. But, i need to find a solution to does not show exception on Output Window VS. But , temporary solution can helps me that ignore one of the FileStream operetor for this sprint .Because, there is no time to change class's structure for this sprint of Project.